# Is it true that gita had 3 author

Tags: resource, gita

**scroll.in** the source

> The First Author wrote most of Adhyayas 1 to 6. The period of writing was of the Older Upanishads and pre-Buddhist, around 600 BCE. The principal philosophical issue is Sannyasa and the solution is Karma yoga (126 verses or 18 per cent).

> The Second Author wrote portions of Adhyaya 8, Adhyayas 13 to 15, 17 and portions of 18.

> The Third Author is the editor and the final arbiter of the document. He wrote the entire Adhyayas 7, 9–12, 16 plus interpolated in the Adhyayas the two others wrote.

So who can we say it is the word of God.
And can you debunk the claim of the website.

Comment: No it all are speculation

Comment: Can you give some proof

Comment: No...and that site is known for factually incorrect claims when it comes to Hinduism and Hindus. Bhagavada Gita itself is part of Mahabharata. It is said to be written by Vyasa. Some western historians wrongly say that it was school of Vyasa(his disciples) but even that can't be proven. In that case Mahabharata itself tells us that it was authored by Vyasa so did Bhagavada Gita.

Comment: @HareKrishna exactly. Infact that site is known for factually incorrect claims ahout Hinduism and Hindus. Plz see my other comment for authorship of Mahabharata and Bhagavada Gita.

Comment: @DarkKnight what do you mean by proof? The speculations given by that website should give authentic sources and proofs. As it's common consesus of historians about the entirety of authorship of Bhagavada Gita(and Mahabharata) by Vyasa or His disciples(as some western historians claim).

Comment: Ok thanks. I just wanted to know weather it was true or false